# flowers of rice?

Tags: word-usage

In China, we grow rice in fields, and there are flowers on it (shown in the image).

I am wondering whether I can just say: ***flowers of rice***.

Does this make any sense to native speakers? Do I need more explanations?
[image]

Comment: I think it is important to know who you will be communicating this information to (a biologist co-worker, paddy tourists, the readership of the local newspaper).  What you call those sprouts/flowers/panicles will depend on your audience.

Comment: Yes, definitely. The target readers are paddy tourists.  I think rice flowers can make sense to the general public.

Comment: "rice flowers" sounds a little odd without some explanation, like it means "flowers made of rice" or something.  "Flowers *of the rice plants*" would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "of" gives a sense of compositional (flowers made out of rice) rather than genitive (flowers from a rice plant). A noun adjunct structure (rice flower) would more clearly communicate genitive.

Comment: If someone told me they were looking at *rice flowers* I would have absolutely no idea what they meant.  I would have to ask a series of questions.  I don't think *rice flower* works on its own.

Answer (score 0):

"Flower" is fine. However, I might use "inflorescence", since grasses (like rice) don't have flowers in the traditional sense.

"Panicle" is (according to Wikipedia) a term for the cluster of flowers such as is found in rice or oats.